# Mass update SQL Server table from Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, dataframe

I loaded a dataframe in Python with 150,000 records.

I have made some changes to the dataframe and now I want to update SQL Server table with the new changes.

How can I do that? The approaches I was thinking of are:

**1.** for loop in python with sending update statement for each record in the dataframe. But that means I have to send 150000 update statements to SQL Server, one statement at the time. It is time consuming and doesn't sound right to me.

**2.** put all update statements in one big string and pass it to SQL server, then execute it the string as dynamic SQL script

**3.** send the key with the updated value in comma, semicolon separated string to SQL. Then split it and update in the SQL.

I will pass a string that looks like this

```
"Key347,V837;Key462,V483;Key953,V363;Key307,V948;Key247,V853;Key364,V877;"
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Write a stored procedure and pass it a [User Defined Table Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/using-user-defined-tables?view=sql-server-2017) with your values and then use a regular SQL update.

Comment: There's [fast_executemany](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany), otherwise the only option I see is to bulk-load the new table and run an `UPDATE .. FROM`.

Comment: @Nickolay fast_executemany for each record in the dataframe?

Comment: Rather run `executemany()` with all the records, with the fast_executemany optimization enabled. This _will_ run many UPDATEs under the hood, and I'm not sure about the number of round-trips to the server -- ideally the driver would be able to pack multiple UPDATEs into a single request, but I'm not sure if this works for SQL Server.